# Segfault with stderr

Tags: c, pipe, stderr, printf

I have a segfault in a weird spot in my code. It's in the last if statement. Any one has an idea why I get segfault?

```
void processArgument(char argument[]){
    FILE *sketcher;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen (argument, "r");
    sketcher = popen(Exec_c, "w");
 if (fp == NULL){
        printf ("Could not open pipe to %s\n", argument);
  exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
 }
    if (sketcher == NULL){
        printf ("Could not open pipe to %s\n", argument);
  exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }else{
        parseFile(fp, sketcher);
        if(fclose(fp)==EOF){
   printf("couldn't close pipe to %s.\n", argument);
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
        if (pclose(sketcher) == -1){                                                 //if (pclose(sketcher) == -1){
            fprintf(stderr, "draw_line error: couldn't close pipe to %s.\n", Exec_c);//fprintf(stderr,"",E);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);    
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest possibility would be that `Exec_c` isn't a valid string.